# Dockerize my node back-end where there is many application stored in

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I want to dockerize my Software back-end ( develop using node). In this back-end, I have 3 applications running. For this, I create one `Dockerfile` and one `docker-compose.yml`.
I provide respectively there content in the following.

1. The error I get:

It says that the the type of subscription doesn't exist:
[image: it say that the the type of subscription doesn't exist]

2. DockerFile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app
COPY ./path/to/my subscryptionFile/ /usr/src/app/

RUN npm ci

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4000

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD ["npm", "run","server"]
```

3. Docker-compose file

```
version:  '3.9'

services:
  # Mongodb services
  mongo_db:
    container_name: db_container
    image:  mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
# This volume path is the one use by default by mongodb to store our data, it's recommanded to use it
    volumes:
      - mongo_db:/data/db

  # Nodejs Api services
  api: 
    build: .
# the 4000 is where our container will run and be accessible, the 3000 one is where our app run in our localhost machine
    ports:
      - "4000:6066"
# # Map out volume here to be able to make change in our code without rebuilding the docker image
#     volumes:
#       - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      PORT: 6066
# We use mongo_db instead of localhost because the app isn't run in localhost but in our container
      MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo_db:27017
      MONGODB_DB: katapuls
# To be sure that the app ddoesn't run if the database connection wasn't make before.
    depends_on:
    - mongo_db
# Make our data persistente, so that they are not deleted when we stop our container
volumes:
  mongo_db: {}
```

4. Architecture of my files

[image: Architecture of my files]

I have a `subscryption.json` file with the different type of subscription, make sure to be added to the container but got the same error.